# Magento 2 - How to get payment methods to load when shipping step has been removed

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.1

I have removed the shipping step from the Magento 2 one page checkout by editing the shipping.js file in this location - vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view

I set the visibility to false: `visible: ko.observable(false)`

And then I comment out the step registration:

`stepNavigator.registerStep(
    'shipping',
    '',
    $t('Shipping'),
    this.visible, _.bind(this.navigate, this),
    10
);`

The shipping step goes away just like a want it to but then no payment methods are being loaded. I have tried to find the reason but so far no luck. Help me please :)